# create tree structure in excel 2010 pivot table

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a employee details data as follows:

Name      Reporting To
Emp 1     Emp 10 
Emp 2     Emp 10
Emp 3     Emp 1
Emp 4     Emp 2

Now, I want to pivot the data like

Emp 10
-Emp 1
--Emp 3

-Emp 2
--Emp 4

**Query 1 :** Excel pivot table allows to group for two level and I am not able to achieve this requirement. Could anyone share your idea how to achieve this?

**Query 2 :** Also, one more report I want to display like below.
Emp Name   Total Number of people Reporting to
========   ===================================
Emp 10     4
Emp 1      1
Emp 2      1
Emp 3      0
Emp 4      0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer by myself. This is not possible directly with excel pivot table. So, I added one more column as Top Level Manager and had put "Emp 10" for all other employees too. When I group with the Top Level Manager first & Reporting To next, I got the count which I expected.